# Gauss law for positive charge densities

Tags: computational-physics, gauss-law, vector-fields, plasma-physics, coulombs-law

I am trying to write a PIC (Particle In Cell) code to simulate plasma physics. I am starting with the simplest case, which is a 1D system with a longitudinal field $E = E(x)$. I am using this article as reference (it has some typos, though)

- Hui-Chun Wu, *JPIC & How to make a PIC code*, [arXiv:1104.3163](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.3163).

In it, finite differences are applied to Gauss Law, which gives:

$$E(x + dx, t) =dx \rho(x,t)/\epsilon_0 + E(x,t)$$

(The article uses another normalisation) I would expect the electric field to vanish as x increases. However, this equation seems to say that if $\rho > 0$, then $E(x + dx) > E(x), \forall x$. This would be the result even for the simplest case, i.e., a single point-charge. Where is the mistake? Thank you!

Comment: This question is equal to another, or am I wrong? Anyway what you say is valid in 3D, not in 1D

Comment: @Mark_Bell It’s a delete-and-repost.

Comment: @G.Smith yes, since the other one wasn’t clear enough. Should I put in the question that it is a delete-and-repost? Thank you

Comment: @Mark_Bell I think it is valid for longitudinal fields. In fact, take a look to equation (15) in the quoted link.

Comment: You can always edit a question to make it clearer. This is preferable to deleting and reposting.

Comment: @G.Smith Thank you, I don’t post here very often so I didn’t know it was preferable.

Comment: @AliEsquembreKucukalic - Do you expect $\rho$ to increase indefinitely or to oscillate?  You cannot pile up charge without the electric field trying to do work to eliminate it.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I expect $\rho(x,t)$ to change with time and use it to update the global $E(x,t)$. But in this question I am thinking of sth quite simple - two positive charges separated some distance $D$, and approximated as Gaussian distributions to computationally get rid of the singularities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The charge density in a PIC code has a finite extension, i.e., $\rho(x) \neq 0$ if $x$ belongs to some interval $[x_p - \Delta x, x_p + \Delta x]$. Thus, the solution comes by imposing the initial conditions far away from the charge equal to zero, i.e.,

$E(x,t) = 0$ for $x << x_p$,

and then keep on updating $E(x)$ until we reach $x_p - \Delta x$ so that $\rho(x_p - \Delta x)\neq 0$. After we cover the interval in which the charge is not zero, the immediate next point will give $E(x_p + \Delta x + 2dx) = \rho(x_p + \Delta x + dx) + E(x_p + \Delta x) = E(x_p + \Delta x)$, i.e., a uniform field which is the correct behavior in a 1D system, where $E(x)$ goes with $1/r^0$.